# Sending sound waves down a pipe to measure water depth -- Destructive interference?

Tags: waves, acoustics, interference

I will be attempting to use sonar in order to measure the height of a groundwater well.
In theory, I will have a device emitting sound waves down a tube made of plastic/metal/rubber.
Do I have to worry about destructive interference based upon the radius of the pipe?

If anyone can point me toward some sources of this I would appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Depends on the size of the tube and the wavelength

Comment: @KonstantinAshkenazy you generally compensate by pulsing the amplitude &/or sweeping the frequency (chirp). you could theoretically do this in continuous wave (CW) conditions, but it would depend on the frequency response of your transducers etc. basically you pulse it for these reasons

Comment: @antimony Can you send me any documentation concerning this? I would truly appreciate it.

Comment: @Hilmar Yes can you please expound upon this? I remember learning about this in physics, but can't really remember exactly how it works.

Comment: @KonstantinAshkenazy i don't know whether you're after pure theory physics or more practical. here's a very simple workshop tutorial to get started https://www.instructables.com/Measuring-water-level-with-ultrasonic-sensor/

Comment: @antimony Thank you so much for this -- the only issue is, the radius of this pipe is too large. If I am using monitoring wells, the radius is going to be relatively small (smaller than 10 cm). I have a limited budget. Do you have any resources to point me toward for this? Thank you.